# Swift tableview in popover doesn't show data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, popover

I am trying to setup a popover view containing a textfield and a tableview, but I couldn't make the tableview to show the data. It would be much appreciated if you could help me on this.

1. On the main ViewController, I put a label to trigger the segue of popover,

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   @IBAction func popover(sender: AnyObject) {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetails", sender: self)
   }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {        
       if segue.identifier == "ShowDetails" {
           if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
               controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
               controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 50)
           }
       }

   }
   func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
       return .None
   }
   }
   ```
2. A PopoverCell is setup for the prototype cell,

   ```
       import UIKit

   class PopoverCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


   @IBOutlet weak var AreaCellLabel: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // Initialization code
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
   }
   ```
3. A PopoverControllerView is set for the popover itself.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class PopoverViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   var areas = [Area]()

      // @IBOutlet weak var NewArea: UITextField!

      // @IBOutlet weak var SaveNewArea: UIButton!
         @IBOutlet weak var subtableView: UITableView!


   override func viewDidLoad() {

   subtableView.dataSource = self
   subtableView.delegate = self

   super.viewDidLoad()

   LoadsampleArea()

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }

   func LoadsampleArea () {

   let area1 = Area(AreaName:"Moountain")!
   let area2 = Area(AreaName:"ByHill")!
   let area3 = Area(AreaName:"Yard")!

   areas += [area1, area2, area3]

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return areas.count
   }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a     cell identifier.
       let cellIdentifier = "AreaCell"
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PopoverCellTableViewCell

   let area = areas[indexPath.row]

   cell.AreaCellLabel.text = area.AreaName
   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
   return cell
   }

   }
   ```
4. and a simple data file to put the data.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class Area {

   var AreaName: String

   init? (AreaName: String) {
   self.AreaName = AreaName

       if AreaName.isEmpty {
       return nil
       }

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi please correct the code formatting. As it is a minor edit, that's why I am leaving it to you

Comment: did u set the delegate and datasource for tableView as self?

Comment: @Nilesh thanks for helping with the editing.

Comment: @Tj3n, I set the delegate and datasource as in the updated question details, but it complains that the data feed (area array) is empty, you can refer to the below feedback to the 1st answer. Did you come across this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `UITableView` object in your `PopoverViewController` class ? I can't see any reference to it.

Maybe your didn't copy-paste it since the textfield is commented too, in this case I'll suggest to check if the delegate an datasource are set property.

Comment: Also after you put the `UITableView` object, be sure to set its `dataSource` and `delegate` properties.

Comment: Did you mean to do a @IBOutlet for the tableview as well? Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: After I do that, it showed me errors,  
>fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
occurring at 
subtableView. dataSource = self   <--    Thread 1 EXC_Bad instruction (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0*0) 

How can I handle this? or there is something wrong I did?

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski, maybe I put the datasource and delegate in a wrong place? also, it complains that the area array is empty. thanks.

Comment: Was your table view created from interface builder or was it copy paste from somewhere else? It looks like your tableview isn't initialized and my guess is that the outlet isn't set

Comment: The table view was created from storyboard, and was drag-drop to create the @IBoutlet. Where should I put the init for tableview? I read a lot of examples but I didn't quite see much of init for the tableview similar to this case. Thank you.

Comment: Your tableview looks then set correctly, I was afraid you copy-pasted the code without creating the outlet from interface builder. Maybe your outlet was deleted, you should verify from interface builder. Also, totally unrelated, you should call `super.viewDidLoad()` just after override `func viewDidLoad()`